# Android WebView - when playing a podcast in the webview, after leaving the screen the sound does not stop

Tags: android, android-webview, podcast

I have the weirdest bug. I am running this exact code to play a popular business podcast:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setInitialScale(1);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

    setContentView(webview);
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.stitcher.com/podcast/entrepreneuronfirecom/entrepreneur-on-fire-tim-ferriss-other-incredible-entrepreneurs");
```

And it works just fine, and I am able to play the podcasts, but the problem is that when I leave  the screen, the podcast keeps on playing.

Would anyone know what needs to be done to prevent that behavior?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something in `onStop()`, such as load a blank page into the `WebView`, or perhaps call `clearView()` on it.

The "bug" that you are seeing is no different than how desktop browsers behave. If you load that URL in a desktop browser, and you switch to a different tab in the browser, or minimize the browser window, the podcast keeps playing.

Answer (score 3):

Call `myWebView.clearView()` in the `onStop()` event of the activity.

The activity and therefore the webview is not necessarily destroyed when it is no longer visible. It is similar  to just minimising a browser on the desktop.

Have a look at the activity [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) for more information.